# why does asp.net core 3.0 reactjs app only come up after refreshing browser?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I upgraded a *.net core 2.2 reactjs* app to *.net core 3.0*. I am running it in Visual Studio 2019. I am getting the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Failed to proxy the request to http://localhost:51719/, because the request to the proxy target failed.
```

If I refresh the loading page, it loads fine. Why is the loading slow or erroring out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The startup for spa application usually takes some time and if the timeout reached you would get an error.

You can increase the timeout via `StartupTimeout` property in `UseSpa()`

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it short:

Angular CLI process takes some time to build the project. If you are running `npm start` in the command line, wait for it to finish before you start the `.net` project using `F5` or...

some people found a workaround for this:
Try to comment out the line:

`spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");`

in `startup.cs` file and use

`spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");`

Hope that makes sense to you.